# Maintain image responsiveness while using section

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently switched to `stellar.js` to add some parallax effects. I had one image inside a `container-fluid` but now i am using sections and fixed background attachment. While i was using `img src=".." class="img-responsive"` image resized to viewport. Now my image wont resize accordingly. All i want is parallax while maintaining responsiveness

HTML

```
<section class="intro" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></section>
```

CSS

```
.intro {
    background: url("/img/banner-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: try background-size: cover;

Comment: solved it by using   background-size: contain;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your .intro section is 100% you should use css attribute `background-size`:

```
.intro {
    background: url("/img/banner-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Please note, that background-size is not supported by IE<9. Head here for more information: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

What sucks is, that you can´t use background-size:cover with background-attachment:fixed in mobile safari. :(